# How to get specific data from Order Product list in Flow?

Tags: dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics, power-automate

Im trying to create an automated word document using flow.

I need the customers address, what inverter they have on our order product list and some info from that inverter. However I can't figure out how to get the inverter's information.

Please see attached screenshots for information.

Cheers,
Chris

[Flow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FAiOz.png)

Comment: I saw your Flow, Entity Installation site has Item Identifier as Order Id and entity Order Product has Item Identifier as Order Id. I think this cannot be the case, two different entity cannot have same Guid, You will have to have addition criteria to get record based on Order Id.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, I ended up sorting it by using the List records feature of common data service the using an ODATA filter query and just filtered by the GUID of an inverter on the order product.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Used an ODATA filter query to filter the products correctly on Orders.

```
salesorderid_value eq (Dynamic Content of Order GUID from Trigger)
```

List all the order products related to the order from the trigger.